# Dojo 1.8 Build Layer Modules not available during Parse

Tags: dojo

In our project we use parse on declarative syntax to instantiate our modules.  We have a build process that builds our dojo, generic and functional layers for us.  In one of our functions, the parser is complaining that some of the modules aren't defined (What's also odd is that the modules aren't being auto required either).  I've confirmed that the layer is included in the page and that the module(s) are included in the layer.  I can "require" the modules after the parse and they return the proper constructors.  No errors are being reported (the attempt to retrieve the module is in a try/catch).

I feel like something silly is happening, but I can't find it. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot would be helpful.

I've tried both parseOnLoad (our default) and calling parse seperately, even after a 10 second timeout.

Comment: If it is only *some* modules, then which ones and why are they special/different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I knew it was something silly.  We had lang="en" instead of lang="en-US".